# How to revert back document to a previous revision

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to restore a Google doc (or any other doucment) in GAS to an earlier revision. I managed to access revisions, even to download an older revision, but how can I restore a document to a specified revision?

Comment: Could you please share how you accessed the revisions @WillemS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- You want to revert to the previous version of Google Docs.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the revision of Google Docs cannot be directly changed by APIs with a script. So as one of several workarounds, I would like to propose to overwrite the Google Docs file using the exported data. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve the exported endpoint from the Google Docs file with the revision ID.

   - In this case, the Google Docs file is exported as the Microsoft Docs file.
2. Retrieve the blob from the exported endpoint.
3. Overwrite the Google Docs with the retrieved blob.

By this flow, the Google Docs file is reverted to the previous version.

### IMPORTANT:

As an important point, when the Google Docs file is exported as the Microsoft Docs file, at the most cases, the overwritten Google Docs files are not changed from the original Google Docs for the version. But I'm not sure that this workaround works perfectly for all cases. So please be careful this.

### Sample script:

The sample script of this workaround is as follows. Before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  var revisionId = "1";  // Please set the revision ID you want to revert.
  var googleDocsFileId = "###";  // Please set the Google Docs file ID.

  var endpoints = Drive.Revisions.get(googleDocsFileId, revisionId).exportLinks;
  var keys = Object.keys(endpoints);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i].indexOf("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument") > -1) {
      var endpoint = endpoints[keys[i]] + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var mediaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint).getBlob();
      Logger.log(mediaData.getBytes().length)
      Drive.Files.update({}, googleDocsFileId, mediaData);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

### Note:

- Even after the Google Docs file was reverted to the previous version, the version of the file can be changed. But before you test above script, I recommend to use a sample Google Docs file.
- When this workaround is used, the files except for Google Docs can be also reverted to the previous version. But in this case, please modify the script.
- If you want to revert perfectly to the previous version, in the current stage, I recommend to manually revert.
- For example, when you want to revert only values of cells, this can be perfectly achieved. You can see it at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57387113/7108653) as the sample case.

### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Revisions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/get)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

#### Updated: February 7, 2020

From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) So please use the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter. It's as follows.

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I am honored reading your out-of-the-box solution. As I come to think about this: the odd thing is that to accomplish what I need (to restore document to previous version) I'ld better not use a Google doc at all. An even easier work-around would be to use a Microsoft Word doc in Drive, which nowadays can be easily viewed and edited (and reverted tot previous version). Seems like this is a challenge that Google shouldn't ignore...

Comment: @WillemS Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. Also I hope for the method and API for directly moving the revisions of Google Docs under the native Google Docs.

Comment: Excellent! I confirm, the solution worked for me to recover corrupted google sheet

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you for your comment. I'm glad about it.

Comment: @Tanaike: How can I add your updated line to the original code ?

Comment: @Mous About your question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, I would like to recommend posting your question as a new question by including more information. By this, it will help users think of the solution. And this is not your question. When you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it. I asked my question here, it would be kind if you can help me » https://stackoverflow.com/q/70702127/12095409

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pair of example functions implemented in [python](/questions/tagged/python) using the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) package.

Firstly, call `gsGetLatestRevisionId` to get the latest revision as a restore point before you start mucking with the Google doc in your app:

```python
from dateutil import parser

def gsGetLatestRevisionId(gc:Resource,gsId:str) -> str:
    '''
    Gets the latest revisionId for a google docs file with id=gsId.
    We can use this as a restore point after manipulating a google spreadsheet 
    :param gc: The authenticated Google drive api discovery.build service
    :param gsId: The google sheets id for the file we want to analyse
    :return: revisionId of the latest revision
    '''
    revisions = gc.revisions().list(fileId=gsId).execute()
    revisionDateIds = {}
    for rd in revisions['revisions']:
        revisionDateIds[parser.parse(rd['modifiedTime'])] = rd['id']
    latestDate = max(revisionDateIds.keys())
    return revisionDateIds[latestDate]
```

Once it has all gone horribly wrong, call `gsRevertToRevision` to restore the spreadsheet to the earlier-identified restore point:

```python
from io import BytesIO
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload

def gsRevertToRevision(gc:Resource,gsId:str,revisionId:str) -> dict:
    '''
    Reverts the google docs file with id gsId to the revision identified by 
    revisionId.
    We use this as a restore point pointer so we can revert a google spreadsheet.
    
    :param gc: The authenticated Google drive api discovery.build service
    :param gsId: the google sheets id for the file we want to revert
    :param revisionId: The google sheet's revision id that we want to revert the file to
    :raises [ValueError]: if unable to download the revision file from Google Drive API.
    :return: result of the update to the restored revision 
    '''
    # Get the name of the spreadsheet
    name = ''.join(gc.files().get(fileId=gsId, fields='name').execute().values()) 
    # Get the download links (exportLinks)
    endPoints = gc.revisions().get(fileId=gsId, revisionId=revisionId, 
                                   fields='exportLinks').execute()
    # Different classes of download links are supported, so we choose the one
    # likely to give us the best outcome
    mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    endPoint = endPoints['exportLinks'][mimeType]
    # We use the protected _http functionality in the Google service 
    # object to download this file with the correct headers in place.
    # Hopefully they don't replace or remove the _http method in future 
    # revisions of the google api python library!
    # The result is a tuple with response json information and the actual 
    # file data in the second object. 
    response, fileData = gc._http.request(endPoint)
    if response.status == 200:
        metaData = {
            'name': name, 'mimeType': mimeType,
            }
        fh = BytesIO(fileData)
        mediaBody = MediaIoBaseUpload(fh, mimetype=mimeType,
            chunksize=1024*1024, resumable=True)
        result = gc.files().update(
            fileId=gsId,
            body=metaData,
            media_body=mediaBody
            ).execute()
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unable to download the revision file from google drive api.')     
    return result
```

This is designed for use with Google spreadsheets, but could be adapted to work with other document types. The trick is to choose the most functional [`exportLink` mime-type](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-export-formats?hl=en) for the particular document. I have not generalised this functionality as this is more of a demonstration of concept. Also, the conversions might introduce artifacts, so I would prefer people not to simply copy and paste without being aware of this potential issue.

`gsRevertToRevision` can, of course, be used standalone and fed any valid `revisionId`, so this meets the general use case requirement posed in the question, at least insofar as revisions go.

Another *"feature"* of this is, unlike other similar solutions, it does not create a file to write the downloaded instance file data to disk. Instead, everything is kept it in RAM. Bear this in mind if you have large files that you want to process in this way as you could end up running out of memory.

### Caveat!

`gsRevertToRevision` works by exporting and then re-importing the document instance. This involves document type conversion (twice) and could result in the loss of data and/or functionality. Make sure that ***every aspect*** of your spreadsheet makes it back in testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Additionally, as you can see in the [revision resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions), you can change the `published` property to mark a particular revision to be the "active one".

To do this from Apps Script you will need to [enable Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), which will allow you to use the API fully. Then you can use the `update` method ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update)), using the desired revision's ID and changing its `published` property to `true`.

Bear in mind that according to the documentation:

> This is only applicable to Google Docs.

Comment: I think this only publishes the revision and doesn't revert document back to a previous revision.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. But TheMaster is right: what you are describing only causes the html version to be based on the older revision. It does not change the document itself. I want to programatically reverse the document to its orginal revision so that my users can edit it afresh.

Comment: That is true, I apologize for the mistake.