# I'd like to inquire about Google Drive ransomware related recovery

Tags: api, google-drive-api, google-apps-activity

I was infected with ransomware while using Google Drive file stream.
That changed all the extensions of the files I could access.
I know how to connect to the Google Drive web and restore each file to a previous version.
However, it takes too much physical time to recover files one by one—more than 30 GB.
**I want to roll back to the state of Google Drive before the incident.**
If you can help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

### There is no way to restore the whole Drive as such, you would need to do it file by file

Programmatically you can

- list all files on your drive with [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- Use the retrieved `files/id` for [Revisions:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- Retrieve `revisions/id` for each file
- For non-Google mimeTypes use [Revissions:delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/delete)
- For Google mimeTypes this does not work, as a workaround:

  Use [Revisions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get) to retrieve the prelast `revisions/id` and export this version with `exportLinks` - see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149716/restoring-specific-version-of-spreadsheet-using-the-google-api) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
But I don't know how to use the method you just told me.
The reason is that I use this service for the first time today.
Could you help me follow you?
Please I beg you.

Comment: Yes, I can do basic coding.
I just asked because I didn't know where to apply your reply.
Can you tell me where to enter the code?

Comment: You need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk), it has [quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) for different languages to help you get started. Once you are comfortable using it, you can find the methods you need to implement following the links in my answer.

Comment: "The authentication flow has completed. You may close this window."We made it this far.
From now on, can I do it the way you told me?
Can you explain a little more?

Comment: After this your code should run and log / printo something to the console  - if you implemented such a request.

Comment: Could you tell me in more detail what you mean?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Python.

Comment: If you follow the [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) you can see that the lines `    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))´ list the files on your Drive and print their names and ids.

Comment: There are some basics in coding, but I'm definitely a beginner.
I'm sorry for bothering you.
But I am desperate because it is a matter of all the files in our company.
Please, I need your help.

Comment: I have now completed number 4 of Python Quickstart.
Are you talking about the work after that?

Comment: I found the phrase you said.
Do you mean to modify there?
If so, how can I modify it?

Comment: I am sorry, what you are asking for is too much to answer in a single answer if you are not familiar with Google APIs given that the necessary logic requires multiple requests, loops and statements for implementation.

Comment: Then can't you help me in any other way?
Or do you know the Korean developer who can solve this problem?
A little hope is fine with me.