# GoogleJsonResponseException: The call from API to drive.revisions.get failed with error : Revision not found: 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The following code is used to reinitialize the file following the execution of the analysis script. The goal is to erase the cells already filled in manually for a new request.

The error is obtained at the end of the analysis process and I cannot track down the source of the problem.

```
    // Before you run the script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.
function resetFile() {//restore previous version of the file
  var revisionId = "1";  // Please set the revision ID you want to revert.
  var googleDocsFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();  // Please set the Google Docs file ID.

  var endpoints = Drive.Revisions.get(googleDocsFileId, revisionId).exportLinks;
  var keys = Object.keys(endpoints);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i].indexOf("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument") > -1) {
      var endpoint = endpoints[keys[i]] + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var mediaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint).getBlob();
      Logger.log(mediaData.getBytes().length)
      Drive.Files.update({}, googleDocsFileId, mediaData);
      break;
    }
  }
}

function resetSource(){//pas nécessaire
   var file= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("FileID").getValue(); 
   var fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(file);  
  fileID.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

Update 2022-01-14

[image]

Comment: The code itself is not enough for us to replicate your issue. Kindly provide examples files and screenshots. Also, could you show what is the analysis process? See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? If you can do, please show the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: My script called `createfile.gs` helps me to create a file. At the end of its execution, it calls `resetFile.gs` to revert to the previous version of the table (the clean version).  
As you can see, the `resetFile` process get stucked at the line 6, because something is wrong with `var revisionId`. Do you have any idea about this error ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, from your showing script, if you are using my sample script at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57898660 , I deeply apologize that my sample script cannot be directly used for your situation. From your replying, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message, in your situation, how about retrieving the 1st existing revision version? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var revisionId = "1";
var googleDocsFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
```

#### To:

```
var googleDocsFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var list = Drive.Revisions.list(googleDocsFileId, { fields: "items(id)" }).items;
if (list.length == 0) throw new Error("No revisions were found.");
var revisionId = list[0].id;
```

#### Reference:

- [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list)

Comment: Hi Tanaike,
You are a champion !
I kept the `googleDocsFileId` var, though.

`var googleDocsFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var list = Drive.Revisions.list(googleDocsFileId, { fields: "items(id)" }).items;
if (list.length == 0) throw new Error("No revisions were found.");
var revisionId = list[0].id;`
Thank you so much !

Comment: @Mous Thank you for replying. Of! Yes! `var googleDocsFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()` is required to use `Drive.Revisions.list`. I also updated my answer. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

// Before you run the script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

```
function resetFile() {
    //restore previous version of the file var revisionId = "1"; // Please set the revision ID you want to revert. 
    var googleDocsFileId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

    // Please set the Google Docs file ID. 
    var endpoints = Drive.Revisions.get(googleDocsFileId, revisionId).exportLinks; 
    var keys = Object.keys(endpoints); 
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
        if (keys[i].indexOf("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument") > -1) { 
            var endpoint = endpoints[keys[i]] + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); 
            var mediaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint).getBlob(); 
            Logger.log(mediaData.getBytes().length) 
            Drive.Files.update({}, googleDocsFileId, mediaData); 
            break; 
        } 
    }
} 

function resetSource() {
    //pas nécessaire 
    var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("FileID").getValue(); 
    var fileID = DriveApp.getFileById(file); 
    fileID.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

Comment: This is really difficult to make sense of without any attempt at line breaks, indentation, or formatting. Please [edit] your answer to improve the readability.