# Revert to specific version of Google sheets with respect to specific date using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, version, revision-history

I have a Google sheet and I am looking to get the previous version which was on a specific date. Let's say, I want to get the version of my Google sheet dated back to 31st December 2022. This version should be created in a new spreadsheet and does not overwrite the existing one. I found a StackOverflow [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886437/how-to-revert-back-document-to-a-previous-revision) proposed by [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) that seems similar to my requirement:

> ```
> function myFunction() {
>  var revisionId = "1";  // Please set the revision ID you want to revert.
>  var googleDocsFileId = "###";  // Please set the Google Docs file ID.
>
>  var endpoints = Drive.Revisions.get(googleDocsFileId, revisionId).exportLinks;
>  var keys = Object.keys(endpoints);
>  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
>    if (keys[i].indexOf("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument") > -1) {
>      var endpoint = endpoints[keys[i]] + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
>      var mediaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint).getBlob();
>      
>      Logger.log(mediaData.getBytes().length)
>      Drive.Files.update({}, googleDocsFileId, mediaData);
>      break;
>    }
>  }
> }
> ```

But this script does not address the specific date version scenario and it overwrites the existing file. I was not able to modify it due to my basic knowledge. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you included code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, [edit] to make sure you do **ALL** the following: 1.Include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, 2. Mention the author's name, and 3. [Quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: @TheMaster if you read the description about the code snippet, you will see I referred to a link from where I have used this code. I hope this answers your concern.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. About `I want to get the version of my Google sheet dated back to 31st December 2022.`, I'm worried that in the case of this, there might be multiple versions on `31st December 2022`. In that case, I cannot know 
 your expected result. Can you provide your detailed expected result? 2. In the current stage, even when your Spreadsheet has the container-bound script, the revision of the script cannot be restored. Is this included in your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your expected result.

Comment: for the first question: `any version of 31st December 2022 will be fine`, 
for the second question: if we generate the previous version in a newly created separate Google sheet then we do not need to restore the script in this version

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to restore the existing Google Spreadsheet by selecting the date as a new Google Spreadsheet.
- From `any version of 31st December 2022 will be fine`, you want to restore one of the versions on 31st December 2022.
- In this case, you are not required to include the container-bound script.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following answer? Unfortunately, I think that in order to achieve your goal, it is required to do the following flow.

1. Retrieve versions using the inputted date.
2. Retrieve the endpoint of XLSX using the retrieved version.
3. Convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet as a new file.

When this flow is reflected in a sample script, I think that your showing script cannot be directly used. In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set `date`. In this case, please use the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` as a string value.

This sample script is for Drive API v2.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const date = "2022-12-31"; // This is from "I want to get the version of my Google sheet dated back to 31st December 2022."
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID. Or, please use SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() if your script is container-bound script.

  let list = [];
  let pageToken;
  do {
    const obj = Drive.Revisions.list(spreadsheetId, { maxResults: 1000, fields: "nextPageToken,items(id,mimeType,modifiedDate)", pageToken });
    const items = obj.items.filter(({ modifiedDate }) => modifiedDate.split("T")[0] == date);
    if (items.length > 0) {
      list = [...list, ...items];
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  if (list.length > 0) {
    const revision = list.pop(); // This is the last version on the date of `date`. If you want to first version on the date, please use list[0] instead of list.pop()
    if (revision.mimeType == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      const endpoint = Object.entries(Drive.Revisions.get(spreadsheetId, revision.id).exportLinks).find(([k]) => k == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
      if (endpoint) {
        const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint[1], { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
        const file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
        const res = Drive.Files.insert({ title: `${file.getName()}_restored`, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [{ id: file.getParents().next().getId() }] }, blob);
        console.log(res.id);
      } else {
        console.error("Endpoint for exporting XLSX was not found.");
      }
    } else {
      console.error("File is not Google Spreadsheet.");
    }
  } else {
    console.error(`No revisions in ${date}.`);
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the last version on "2022-12-31" is restored as a new Google Spreadsheet. The Spreadsheet is created in the same folder as the target Spreadsheet.
- If you want to restore the 1st version on "2022-12-31", please modify `const revision = list.pop();` to `const revision = list[0];`.

#### References:

- [Method: revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/revisions/list)
- [Method: revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/revisions/get)
- [Method: files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/insert)

### Updated on December 13, 2023

In the current stage, when Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services, Drive API v3 is automatically used. In the official document, Drive API v3 has already been used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) In the current stage, the users can select V3 and V2.

If you enable Drive API at Advanced Google services, Drive API v3 is automatically set. In this case, the above sample script is modified as follows.

This sample script is for Drive API v3.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const date = "2022-12-31"; // This is from "I want to get the version of my Google sheet dated back to 31st December 2022."
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID. Or, please use SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId() if your script is container-bound script.

  let list = [];
  let pageToken;
  do {
    const obj = Drive.Revisions.list(spreadsheetId, { maxResults: 1000, fields: "nextPageToken,revisions(id,mimeType,modifiedTime)", pageToken });
    const items = obj.revisions.filter(({ modifiedTime }) => modifiedTime.split("T")[0] == date);
    if (items.length > 0) {
      list = [...list, ...items];
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  if (list.length > 0) {
    const revision = list.pop(); // This is the last version on the date of `date`. If you want to first version on the date, please use list[0] instead of list.pop()
    if (revision.mimeType == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      const endpoint = Drive.Revisions.get(spreadsheetId, revision.id, { fields: "exportLinks" }).exportLinks["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"];
      if (endpoint) {
        const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
        const file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
        const res = Drive.Files.create({ name: `${file.getName()}_restored`, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, parents: [file.getParents().next().getId()] }, blob);
        console.log(res.id);
      } else {
        console.error("Endpoint for exporting XLSX was not found.");
      }
    } else {
      console.error("File is not Google Spreadsheet.");
    }
  } else {
    console.error(`No revisions in ${date}.`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my sheet is as old as `2021-09-13 (yyyy-MM-dd)`, but when I input any date like `2022-11-12 , 2022-12-31 , 2021-09-13`, it only shows one output: `No revisions in ${date}` .

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. About `However my sheet is as old as 2021-09-13 (yyyy-MM-dd), but when I input any date like 2022-11-12 , 2022-12-31 , 2021-09-13, it only shows one output: No revisions in ${date} .`, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. But, from your reply, I'm worried that the revision data might not be able to be correctly retrieved. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @EagleEye Now, I tested my script with "2017-06-28" on my Google Spreadsheet, I confirmed that the script worked and the restored Spreadsheet was created. I deeply apologize for this situation. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. By the way, can you test my script using a newer date? Because I would like to recommend confirming whether my script works in your situation.